# Access with computer name on samba

Tags: samba, debian

I installed samba and configured. I can access via IP from Windows machine. But i can not access with Computer Name.

How can i do this ?

I found a netbios_name and i added after workgroup in smb.conf file but it does not work for me.

Comment: Could be duplicate with https://superuser.com/questions/43494/how-do-you-add-an-ip-address-hostname-pair-to-the-host-file-in-windows-7

Comment: netbios is really ancient (even m$ft [win2k & before] don't use it anymore as it only allowed 253 machines on the network & was not internet compatible).  if you want to use a name instead of ip.address; it's best done via HOSTS or DNS, which is the same for windows & ubuntu (just the HOSTS file is stored in different places; /etc/hosts for ubuntu - for windows refer to the link @dubis provided)

Comment: @guiverc please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

netbios is really ancient; even m$ft stopped supporting it after w2k (win2000) as it only allowed 253 machines on the network & was not  routable or internet compatible (without ugly tricks)

if you want to use a name instead of ip.address; it's best done via HOSTS or DNS, which is the same for windows & ubuntu if you exclude the HOSTS file being stored in different places; /etc/hosts for ubuntu, for windows refer to the link @dubis provided in an earlier comment.

Comment: hello, my ip is 192.168.1.33, and use debian. I added /etc/hosts file 192.168.1.33 PATA but when i try on windows machine ping PATA it does not work. If i try ping 192.168.1.33 it works.

Comment: the HOSTS file has to be amended on every machine where you want it to work. did you modify the windoze machine too?

Comment: we have 20 windows machine, i can not modify every machine. Are there any method to change on linux machine only

Comment: DNS [domain name service] is your answer; where machines ask for an IP address, gateway etc.  Most home users use their routers for this function; but enterprise grade devices (& decent home ones) allow modification & addition of entries (without memory limits). Modify the DNS tables on your router/dns-device; or move the DNS functions to a device (pc) where you can have one device that does it for all machines.